# ln: failed to create symbolic link : No such file or directory

Tags: symbolic-link

So I just moved over to Ubuntu and cannot find a solution to this problem anywhere. I'm installing Maya 2020 and want to create a symbolic link using the following

`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre16.so.3 /usr/autodesk/maya2020/lib/libpcre16.so.0`

I get the following error :

`ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/autodesk/maya2020/lib/libpcre16.so.0': No such file or directory`

The libpcre16.so.3 file exists in the /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu folder. The error I'm getting is that the libpcre16.so.0 file does not exist. How can it exist before I make a symbolic link ? From what I know symbolic links are somewhat like shortcuts in windows.

Any help ?

Comment: You are correct, the link name should not exist before you make it, but in this case, one of the directories in the path `/usr/autodesk/maya2020/lib` (probably) doesn't exist. You are trying to create a link in a non-existent directory, is what the error says.

Comment: @Jos I just checked in the file manager and the directory indeed does not exist. I'm following the official guide. https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/simplecontent/content/installing-maya-2020-ubuntu.html when will the directory be created ? Or should I ask this question somewhere else.

Comment: It doesn't say in the installation instructions, and `/usr/` is not a usual place to install applications on Ubuntu. However, as I see it, for now you could get away with creating the path yourself: `sudo mkdir /usr/autodesk` and so on.